# RPM Error during import in FEdora 13

Tags: fedora

I am trying to install mysql workbench on fedora 13,During that process wen i give the below command as root:
rpm --import http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
I get the below error :
error: http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi: import failed.
Plz assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=217480 the key might be already installed. See what happens if you try to install packages from remis repo.

Comment: Thanks mistapink.It was already installed.NOw successfully installed workbench.Thanks again